# Float object with two different values

Tags: java

I'm having trouble printing a Float value into a report.
When I inspect the object, it shows two values.
I would expect when I print this value into a report, the value would be 80.914055.
But it prints 80.789055.

[image: Float showing two values]

The value is coming from a dll writen in Fortran. There is a method that retrieves the value from the dll and return as a Java float (80.914055).

```
public float getN1(){
    return ttoutn.getCRUICM(0);
};
```

There is another class that calls the method above. But uses method.invoke() instead.

```
Object returnedObject = method.invoke(calculationModule);
```

With method.invoke(), the primitive float is wrapped in an object Float. It seems that the value inside Float is correct (80.914055), as shown above. But once you use System.out.println(), it prints as another value (80.789055).

I am kind of clueless of what might be happening.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Otherwise, your question may get closed due to insufficient details

Comment: The first value is the stored *float* value, while the second is the Float.toString() method call. But I have no idea why they are so different.

Answer (score 2):

Because java uses [IEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) for floating point math.  Which means you're going to get weird stuff sometimes.

If the precision is really important, use [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).  There's great guide to [this stuff here](http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/java/).

Comment: Interesting. So this might be a problem of converting one type of representation to another? Or this would be expected in Java as general?

Comment: It's not java per se, it's the JVMl, but more so it's any runtime that uses the  IEE754 "power of 2" method of of representing floating point numbers, so that includes javascript, some C compilers and dozens of other things ( Including Fortran compilers).

Check with the whomever's providing you that Fortran DLL -- if the exact precision is important have them pass it back as a string instead and read it with BigDecimal.